# How to nest a multicolumn object under a single column within a R dataframe

Tags: r

Imagine that you have a matrix such as:

`a = matrix(1:20, 4, 5)`

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    5    9   13   17
[2,]    2    6   10   14   18
[3,]    3    7   11   15   19
[4,]    4    8   12   16   20
```

where columns 1-4 are the values of a 4-dimension data point and column 5 is the *label*.

Is there an elegant way to nest the 4-d vector under one single column with a data frame using native R functions? (Permission to the web to download more dedicated libraries from web is restricted.)
Basically, I want to end up with something like this:

```
          Data  Label 
1    1 5 9  13    17
2    2 6 10 14    18
3    3 7 11 15    19
4    4 8 12 16    20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tidyverse` way would be to group by the last column and then to `nest` the remaining data; this requires a `data.frame` or `tibble` though instead of a `matrix`.

```
library(tidyverse)
a %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    group_by(V5) %>%
    nest()
## A tibble: 4 x 2
#     V5 data
#  <int> <list>
#1    17 <tibble [1 × 4]>
#2    18 <tibble [1 × 4]>
#3    19 <tibble [1 × 4]>
#4    20 <tibble [1 × 4]>
```

To give a different example, consider the `iris` dataset. You could group data by `Species` and then `nest`

```
iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    nest()
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Species    data
#  <fct>      <list>
#1 setosa     <tibble [50 × 4]>
#2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 4]>
#3 virginica  <tibble [50 × 4]>
```

This resulting `data` column can be easily operated on using one of the `purrr::map*` functions.

---

In base R you can do

```
icol <- 5   # The index of the label column 
df <- data.frame(Label = a[ ,icol], Data = I(lapply(as.data.frame(t(a[, -icol])), c)))
df
#   Label         Data
#V1    17  1, 5, 9, 13
#V2    18 2, 6, 10, 14
#V3    19 3, 7, 11, 15
#V4    20 4, 8, 12, 16
```

Here `df` is a `data.frame` with a `list` column `Data`.

Comment: True, `tidyverse` would do it but I was looking for native R commands as the script might be ported to a machine which does not have access to the web to download this library.

Comment: @flamenco So why is `a` a `matrix`; considering that part of it are data and another part corresponds to a label, a `data.frame` would make much more sense. A `matrix` can have only one data type.

Comment: @flamenco I've made an edit to include a base R solution; please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

This is an idea that outputs a different object, but can give you an idea as to how to format it,

```
setNames(split(c(t(a[,-(5)])), rep(seq(4), each = 4)), a[,5])

#$`17`
#[1]  1  5  9 13

#$`18`
#[1]  2  6 10 14

#$`19`
#[1]  3  7 11 15

#$`20`
#[1]  4  8 12 16
```